# How to make circle page indicator while scrolling images in horizontal scroll view?

Tags: android, android-layout

To use circle page indicator, what dependencies should I use?

This is my dependency file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.1.0'
compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.1@aar'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead I suggest you to use simple horizontal LinearLayout in the same layout with ViewPager, below it. And fill this LinearLayout with as many TextViews as there are pages in ViewPager. And put html code of circle into each TextView as the text. Just simply use `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#9675"));`
And dynamically then change color of selected circle when page is changed, also add onClickListener on each TextView to change page on ViewPager. The same idea is used [here](http://vrinfosystem.com/blogs/blog/android-intro-slider-guide). Pay attention to method **addBottomDots**:

```
private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
    dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

    int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_for_active_dot);
    int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_for_inactive_dot);

    dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i] = new TextView(this);
        dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
        dots[i].setTextSize(35);
        dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);
        dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
    }

    if (dots.length > 0)
        dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[currentPage]);
}
```

And call it every time page changed:

```
 public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        addBottomDots(position);
        //... and so on, your code goes here
 }
```

Hope it helps.